# Get data Self reference

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a self reference model.
I  want get data with linq.i want when status is ok return data.but if parent status is ok all of child return ok or pending or deleted.
how can i do this.

```
var model = _efComment.List(p => p.PostId == postId);
        var list = model.ToList()
            .Where(p => p.ComentStatus == ComentStatus.Ok)
            .Where(x => x.Reply == null)
            .ToList();using System.Collections.Generic;
```

---

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using DomainModel.Classes;

namespace DomainModel
{
    public class Comment : BaseFieldsTables
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string WriterName { get; set; }
        public string WriterEmail { get; set; }
        public string WriterWebsite { get; set; }

        public int PostId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PostId")]
        public Post Post { get; set; }

        public Comment Reply { set; get; }

        public int? ReplyId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Children { get; set; }
        public ComentStatus ComentStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace DomainModel
{
    public enum ComentStatus
    {
        Ok = 1,
        Pending = 2,
        Deleted = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please refine this part `I want when status is ok return data.but if parent status is ok all of child return ok or pending or deleted`. What do you want to get?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  What is the child property?  Do you want ONLY the child records that are OK or only the _parent_ records where ALL child records are OK?

Comment: @DStanley I update my post.all data that is ok status

Comment: @TomSmith as I can see, you haven't yet updated query description. You want to status OK return data but parent status is OK or deleted pending all?